# How can select text in a single window in a multi-window configuration?

Tags: osx, copy-paste

When I have two buffers open side by side in as terminal (as shown in the screenshot), I cannot simply select text in a single buffer for copy and paste purpose. The selection will span across them, which is expected because it is how the terminal works.

[image]

My question is: is it possible to copy the text via Crtl-space and then put it in OSX's clip broad? (e.g. pipe the selected text to `pbcopy`?)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `shell-command-on-region` to send the region's text to `pbcopy`.

```lisp
(defun osx-copy-to-clipboard (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (message (if (zerop (shell-command-on-region beg end "pbcopy")) "copied" "copy failed")))
```