# mark-whole-region and pbcopy without losing current point/region

Tags: hydra

I wrote a hydra today (I think my very first one) - I always do `Meta-| pbcopy` after doing a `C-x h`, so why not let hydra help out:

```el
    (global-set-key
     (kbd "C-x h")
     (defhydra hydra-my-mark-whole-buffer
       (:body-pre (mark-whole-buffer))
       "hydra-my-mark-whole-buffer"
       ("h" mark-whole-buffer "this was not needed")
       ("p" my-pbcopy "Meta-| pbcopy")))
    
    
    ;; https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13177
    (defun my-pbcopy (beg end)
      (interactive "r")
      (message (if (zerop (shell-command-on-region beg end "pbcopy")) "copied" "copy failed")))
```

(btw I'm always in `emacsclient -nw` mode)

Anyway, I'd like two more things:

- not lose the point/position
- if a region was marked before calling the hydra, if should stay that way after `pbcopy` has been done.

How can I tweak my code to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if you want to run a command but maintain the initial point, you would wrap the function in `(save-excursion ...)`

From the documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/save_002dexcursion.html:

> In Emacs Lisp programs used for editing, the save-excursion function
> is very common. It saves the location of point, executes the body of
> the function, and then restores point to its previous position if its
> location was changed. Its primary purpose is to keep the user from
> being surprised and disturbed by unexpected movement of point.

Comment: thank you, along with save-excursion, i ended up adding a '(deactivate-mark)' and a hydra ':exit t' to the final solution

Comment: Awesome. Glad to see alternative ways to tackle the same problem.